# How to get inserted and updated objects from NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousChangesNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I want to get the inserted and the update objects from `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousChangesNotification` to do some check on them.

Objects can be of two kind of classes: "**Alpha**" and "**Beta**". Both classes have the

```
property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name
```

which is the one I should check.

How do I get it?

The following code doesn't work because it says "name" is an unknown selector:

```
-(void) checkObjects
{
  NSDictionary *insertedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey: @"inserted"];
  NSDictionary *updatedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey: @"updated"];

  for(NSManagedObject *obj in insertedObjects){
    if([obj.entity.managedObjectClassName isEqualToString:@"Alpha"]){

      Alpha *alpha = (Alpha*) obj;

      if (alpha.name isEqualToString:@"xyz"){
        //Do some check
      }

    }else if([obj.entity.managedObjectClassName isEqualToString:@"Beta"]){

      Beta *beta = (Beta*) obj;

      if (beta.name isEqualToString:@"xyz"){
        //Do some check
      }
    }
  }

}
```

If I change:

```
Alpha *alpha = (Alpha*) obj;

Beta *beta = (Beta*) obj;
```

To:

```
Alpha *alpha = (Alpha*) obj.entity;

Beta *beta = (Beta*) obj.entity;
```

alpha = Alpha <-- It is the name of the class, not of the object I want!

beta = Beta <--- It is the name of the class, not of the object I want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`, the objects in `userInfo` are not managed objects, they're managed object IDs. That is, instances of `NSManagedObjectID`. If you want to look up attributes on the managed object, you need to get the object corresponding to the ID. Something like

```
NSDictionary *insertedObjectIDs = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
for(NSManagedObjectID *objID in insertedObjects) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObject *obj = [self.managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:objID error:&error];
    ....continue...
}
```

You may need to change that if self doesn't have a managed object context.

Also, on a slight tangent-- it's generally better to use `NSInsertedObjectsKey` instead of `@"inserted"` and `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` instead of `@"updated"`. Apple *probably* won't change the key names, but they could, so using the key names instead of string literals is a better choice.